# Render Multiple PartialView by clicking on relevent tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, tabs

I searched a lot and i found many soloution on stackoverflow and on other sites and I tried many of them but none of them worked for me. So thats Why I am posting this question.
I Created three partialviews. every partialview have submit form on it in which we can creat records. On Index View I created 3 tabs and rendered partialviews in these three tabs. When page loads, all the three partial views (forms) loads. I just want to load a single partial view when page loads. Then the other views/forms should load when user click on tabs. 
lets suppose if user click on "Classes" tab then the classesPartialView should be loaded in this tab and same for other tabs.

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="nav">
```

Student
    Classes
    Categories

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="student">
 @Html.Action("CreateStudent", "StudentRecords")
</div>
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="class">
@Html.Action("CreateClass", "StudentRecords")
</div>
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="category">
@Html.Action("CreateCategory")

</div>
```

EDIT:

```
  $(function () {
$("#tabs").tabs({
    beforeLoad: function (event, ui) {
        ui.jqXHR.error(function () {
            ui.panel.html(
    "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. " +
    "If this wouldn't be a demo.");
        });
    }
});
```

});

EDIT 2 (updated):

```
  @model IEnumerable<MvcApplication.tbStudentInfo>
@using MvcApplication.Models;

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Navigation Tabs";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

}

<h2>Index</h2>

<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



<div role="tabpanel" class="nav">

<ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li  role="presentation" ><a href="#student"  data-toggle="tab">Student</a></li>
    <li  role="presentation" ><a href="#class"   data-toggle="tab">Classes</a></li>
    <li  role="presentation" ><a href="#category"   data-toggle="tab">Categories</a></li>

  </ul>


  <div class="tab-content">

<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="student">
@Html.Action("CreateStudent", "StudentRecords") 
</div>
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="class">

</div>
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="category"></div>


  </div>



</div>



<script type='text/javascript'>

 $(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs({
            beforeLoad: function (event, ui) {
                ui.jqXHR.error(function () {
                    ui.panel.html(
            "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. " +
            "If this wouldn't be a demo.");
                });
            }
        });
    });


var isClassLoaded = false;
$('#class').click(function() {
  if(isClassLoaded = false) {

    return;
  }
  $(this).load('@Html.Action("CreateClass", "StudentRecords")'); 
  isClassLoaded = true; 
}


</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var isCategoryLoaded = false;
$('#category').click(function() {
  if(isCategoryLoaded) {
    return;
  }
  $(this).load('@Html.Action("CreateCategory", "StudentRecords")'); 
  isClassLoaded = true; 
}
</script>
```

Comment: There is no reason why you cant have 3 forms which each submitted separately - what was the problem?

Comment: Stephen: I have three different forms. I want to load each form in tab by clicking on tab. means when user click on tab then form load. Basic problem is with form loading. When Index page loads, all the forms in tabs loads.

Comment: You would to use javascript/jquery and handle the click event of each tab to load the corresponding form, but whats wrong with loading all 3 forms when the page is rendered?

Comment: I am new to JQuery/Javascript. As I am internee so its my assignment given by company. The say due to performance issue load only one tab page loads and then if user click on any other tab then corresponding partialview loads. I hope now you got the problem

Comment: But you question indicates you had a problem when the 3 forms were loaded. If a use clicks on 2 or 3 tabs, then 2 or 3 forms will be loaded so you still have the same problem in the end.

Comment: brother I edited the question. I just want to load only one View when Index page loads. PartialViews in other tabs should not load unless user clicks on tabs.

Comment: OK, will post answer shortly

Comment: No problem, but your edit still shows `@Html.Action` It need to be `@Url.Action`

Comment: when I use Url.Action nothing display in tabs as I am using partialviews. when i change to Html.Action then result displays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifying an action link for each tab will load the contents via ajax

View

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcApplication.tbStudentInfo>
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Navigation Tabs";
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2>Index</h2>
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#student">Student</a></li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Classes", "CreateClass", "StudentRecords")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Categories", "CreateCategory", "StudentRecords")</li>
  </ul>
  <div id="student">
    @Html.Action("CreateStudent", "StudentRecords") // load this initially
  </div>
</div>
```

Script (include jquery and jquery-ui)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#tabs").tabs();
</script>
```

Note, you will need to remove the `[ChildActionOnly]` attribute from the `CreateClass` and `CreateCategory` methods if you have added them.

Comment: brother I implemented your logic but still all the tabs are loading on page load. I used breakpoints to check. and is used Html.Action instead of Url.Action. because Url.Action is not rendering/displaying anything in tabs.

Comment: You cant use `@Html.Action` - that is parsed on initial load so all the forms are loading. Did you remove the `[ChildActionOnly]` attributes (assuming you had then on controller methods). Put a breakpoint on the scripts a check if there are any console errors.

Comment: Note also I was missing quote in `$('#class)click()` - should be `$('#class')click()`

Comment: brother i corrected it.. I tried your code with different changes but still now results in tabs.. It shows all the three forms on single tab. now I am looking to solve this problem by using switch statement if its possible

Comment: @MuzamilRafique, I don't use jquery tabs but I have tested this with 3 empty divs on a page and it works fine. A switch statement will do nothing to solve your problem. You need to load the 2nd and 3rd forms using ajax. If they are loading on the same tab, check the `id` of the elements - the jquery selectors may be wrong.

Comment: Stephen Muecke I updated the code with your suggestions. I got the result. Tabs loads but when my team lead used debugger with checkpoints all the tabs were loading without any click. But I really appreciate your help. Thanks for your attention and time.

Comment: Then you have done something else wrong. `$('#class').click(function()` means the code will **not** load the `CreateClass` method until you click the element with `id="class"`

Comment: I updated the View code in question. Kindly check this code may be I  am doing wrong

Comment: I'm not familiar with jquery tabs, but I suspect the issue is the selectors. Try giving your 2nd <li> element `id=classtab"` and then change the script to `$('#classtab').click(function() { ... $('#class').load('@Url.Action(...` (ditto for the 3rd li element)

Comment: I Tried but its still loading all tabs. After First tab load debugger moves towards 2nd tab to load and then to third without any click on tabs

Comment: I don't have time to test with jquery tabs right now, but now you have included the full code, I'll have a look at it in a few hours.

Comment: Ok no problem take your time :) and thanks for the help.

Comment: @MuzamilRafique, I have updated my answer. jQuery tabs does everything you need out of the box. Just cut and paste the code above into your view (this is copied from my test project which is working fine). You don't need any scripts except `$("#tabs").tabs();`

Comment: No problem, but I noticed you had previously accepted my answer even when it was not fully working for you - you shouldn't do that - if its useful, up-vote, but don't accept until it solves the problem :)

Comment: that is right. Actually it you can only vote up or accept if the answer solved your problem or is most helpful to solve the problem. so it was most helpful so far thats why i accpeted :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke once again good answer followed an helping conversation +1 for your answer. However if there are 10 tabs and a every tab is returning a table then how to handle. Any clue is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @User, should make no difference whether you have 2 tabs or 100. If you are having a problem with your code, you should post a question with the details so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to load separate form for each tab where each form is a partial view. I will use server side coding (razor) with switch statement and a viewbag. Viewbag will store an integer variable of tab index and in index.chtml I will have a switch statement which renders different partial view for each tab. Note that the index page need to be refreshed (calling index action with tab index as a parameter) when a tab is pressed.